# Moderator dialog content very spaced out

Tags: bug, design, css, moderator-tools

There is a lot of extra space around the content in the "mod" dialog on posts.

[image]

I recall the "actions" link/title being on the left (along with the occasionally relevant "info" link), rather than below the X.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm not able to reproduce this in Chrome 32.0.1700.107 on OS X.

Comment: Internet Explorer 9